# How to change GWT DatePicker month label language

Tags: gwt, internationalization, datepicker

I would like to know if it's possible to change the language of labels in the GWT DatePicker ?
in my searchs, I understand it's possible to play with gwt internationalization, but my pb is not the date format, but the month label. exemple :"Jun" or "Juin", "February" or Fevrier"

Is someone can help me to find these month names to fill my constants files ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT date-picker uses `DateTimeFormat`, and there are implementations of this class for almost languages.

To activate a new locale for your app you have to do two things:

- Activate that language in your module.gwt.xml, so as the gwt compiler generates permutations for the language:

  <extend-property name="locale" values="es,de" />
- Call your application with a parameter to get the appropriate permutation:

  http://my.host.name/my_module/index.html?locale=es

Then Datepicker should show week and month names in the appropriate language